# How can I solve problem with output under g++?

Tags: c++

In Linux I have a line that works:

```cpp
printf ("Semaphore: %d\n", sem_id);
```

But when I write:

```cpp
std::cout << "Semaphore: " << sem_id;
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: perhaps you just need to add `<< std::endl`.  You certainly need to define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that first row is written in `C`, while second one is `C++`.

You probably need an end-of-line marker such as the one you used in the first one (**std::endl**).

```
std::cout << "Semaphore: " << sem_id << std::endl;
```

Output are line-buffered by default. However, it should have shown up when your program terminates in every case.